# How to use grequest to automatically reconnect after grequest timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, aiohttp, grequests

How does grequests do something like'requests' time out auto reconnect.

```
import time
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
for i in range(1,1000):
    s = requests.Session()
    s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3))
    s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3))
    header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
    }
    url = 'https://google.com'
    try:
        r = s.post(url,headers=header, timeout=5)
        print(r.text)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
```

The above is the effect I got through the request, but that is because the request has been encapsulated.

How to use grequests to achieve, below is my grequests code.

```
import grequests
import requests
import time
import json
header = {
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
        }
        url = 'https://google.com'
        # data = {'pouchNo': str(hhh).strip("['").strip("']"),
        # 'year': '2021'}
        req_list = [grequests.request("POST", url=url, headers=header, data={'pouchNo': str(i).strip("['").strip("']"),
                                                                             'year': '2021'}) for i in a]
        res_list = grequests.map(req_list)
        for xxxxxx in res_list:
            jsondata = json.loads(xxxxxx.content.decode())
            try:
                print(str(xxxxxx.request.body.replace("pouchNo=", "").replace("&year=2021", "")) + "\t" + jsondata[
                    'msg'] + "\t" + jsondata['data'])
            except KeyError:
                print(str(xxxxxx.request.body.replace("pouchNo=", "").replace("&year=2021", "")) + "\t" + jsondata[
                    'msg'])
```

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I tried it, but it still returns NONE without retrying to connect, but I can use it like this in requests

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA thanks,I found that I moved the import grequests to the top and it succeeded. thank you very much.